# undefined method `model_name' for #<Class:0x007f043631a380>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I ran through similar problems here but nothing seems to match my problem. I got the error `undefined method model_name for #<Class:0x007f043631a380>`. It points to line #1 of my /app/views/classes/new.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_for @class do | f | %>
    <div class = “form-group”>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: ‘form-control’ %>
```

My app/controllers/classes_controller.rb:

```
class ClassesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @class = Class.new
    end
end
```

My app/models/class.rb:

```
class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
     validates :name, presence: true
     validates :teacher, presence: true
     validates :day, presence: true
     validates :start_time, presence: true
     validates :duration, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

I am very new to RoR and don't really know where to look for a problem. Could you give me direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seem good. It is probably because class is a reserved word in rails : https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/

Try to name your models and controllers something that would not look like some ruby code.

EDIT: What Roman says is correct. Your controller is always plural. Try renaming your controller first as ClassesController.

Comment: Renaming to plural didn't change anything. Renaming every Class into Klass did the thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The `Class.new` line is probably unintentionally referencing the Ruby class [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Class.html). You could try namespacing your `Class`, for instance:

```
module MyModels
  class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

and then using `MyModels::Class` would *probably* work, but I try to avoid naming things `Class`. I'm not sure, since you have 2 classes at the root named the same if there's any other way to specify which you're referencing, and if you specifically `require` and re-define `Class`, I'm not even sure what types of problems would ensue, but I'm sure it wouldn't be my ideal afternoon.

One thing that I often see done, when the name is needed, is to name custom `Class` classes and `class` variables as `Klass` and `klass`. Most coders (that I know, at least), wouldn't even blink twice seeing something like that named with a **K**.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your controller and views name is plural.  Try ClassesController and views/classes/new.html.erb.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a reserved keyword in rails and ruby as your model name.

Your class name should be like SchoolClass or something like that.